# Multiply each row of a matrix with it's conjugate transposed numpy

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I have a `numpy.ndarray` variable `A` of size `MxN`. I wish to take each row and multiply with it's conjugate transposed. For the first row we will get:

```
np.matmul(np.expand_dims(A[0,:],axis=1),np.expand_dims(A[0,:].conj(),axis=0))
```

we get an `NxN` sized result. I want the final result for the total operation to be of size `MxNxN`.

I can fo this with a simple loop which iterates over the rows of `A` and concatenates the results. I wish to avoid a for loop for a faster run time with SIMD operations. Is there a way to do this in a single code line with broadcasting?

Otherwise, can I do something else and somehow reshape the results into my requierment?

Answer (score 0):

The next code does what the same as your code snippet but without for-loop. On the other hand, it uses `np.repeat` twice, so you will need to benchmark both versions and compare them to test their memory/time performance.

```py
import numpy as np

m, n = A.shape

x, y = A.conj().repeat(n, axis=0), A.reshape([-1, 1]).repeat(n, axis=1)
B = (x * y).reshape([m, n, n])
```

### How it works

Basically `x` holds the conjugate values of the array `A` in a single column and then is repeated `n` times on the column axis (it has a shape `m*n by n`).

`y` repeats each row in the conjugate matrix of `A`, `n` consecutive times (its final shape is `m*n by n` also)

`x` and `y` are multiplied element-wise and the result is unwrapped to a matrix of shape `m by n by n` stored in `B`

Answer (score -1):

A list comprehension comprehension could do the trick:

```
result = np.array([np.matmul(np.expand_dims(A[i,:],axis=1), np.expand_dims(A[i,:].conj(),axis=0)) for i in range(A.shape[0])])
```